# Database table design for redundancy

Tags: sql-server, database-design

(with SQL Server 2008)  I have a big table (~50M records) that is fully normalized.  There are 4 primary columns, and one of the them has only three possible entries- A, B, and C.  The issue is, often there is much redundancy for this column.  That is to say, there can be many records with value A, and then many repeated records that are identical in all respects, except with value B (and/or C).  This redundancy does not always happen, but it's frequent enough that it greatly increases the record count and I wish to be rid of it.

My idea is that instead of A, B, C being choices for a column, I've thought about creating 3 bit columns titled A, B, C.  Then in the case of the aforementioned redundancies for these values, I don't have to create repeated records, but instead just have one record and then flag the A, B, and/or C columnns as necessary.

These seems unorthodox so I thought I'd see what the experts think.  One thing is that there would be three different uniqueness contraints for this table, each including all the other primary keys plus one of the three flag columns.

[EDIT] To clarify on the meaning of "many repeated records", one of the other PK's is a date column.  So for example, there could be 1000 records of different dates with entry A, and then another 1000 records of the same dates (and other columns identical) but with entry B.  So that is how even with only three choices there can still be lots of redundancy.

Comment: Sometimes it's okay to denormalize.

Comment: You can't have "many repeated records that are identical in all respects" except for the 4th column that takes A OR B or C. You have at most 3. And you should have one unique constraint because of this. It isn't clear what you mean. And 50 million isn't very much...

Comment: I've edited the question to hopefully better explain the "many repeated" scenario.  Admittedly 50 mill might not be much for many tasks, but the fact that so much of it is potentially duplicated makes me think I need to do try to optimize the situation.

Comment: Can you change the datetime to smalldatetime and suppress duplicates that way? eg resolve to nearest minute not 3.33 milliseconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating a separate table that stores these "flags", foreign key'd back to your original table?

Table1 (original table)
----------------------
PriKey1 (PK for Table1)
 
Col1
Col2

Table2 (new table)
------------------
PriKey2 (PK for Table2)
PriKey1 (FK to Table1)
A
B
C

Comment: Yes, I should have realized this immediately. Must not be thinking straight.  As many people have commented that 50M records is "not that much", I might first try to quantify the performance drain and see if this is worth the effort.  And sorry I can't upvote other comments or whatever, this is my first q.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have "many repeated records that are identical in all respects" except for the 4th column in the PK that takes one of A OR B or C. This means to me that you have at most 3 rows (over the other 3 PK columns) differentiated by either A or B or C

This means you should have one unique constraint because of this.

I'd do *nothing* based on this and also

- a row with A is a different row with C
- only 50 millions
- it's simple (no extra tables or fancy bit columns)
- no stated performance issues (until you add extra tables or fancy bit columns)
- you have a clear, normalised schema

Edit:

Your redundancy isn't in the ABC column.  The row multiplication is caused by the datetime.

Can you change the datetime to smalldatetime and suppress near-duplicates that way? eg resolve to nearest minute not 3.33 milliseconds? Or for SQL Server 2008 use datetime2 and pick your resolution

Comment: sorry I think there's still confusion.  The dates, and every column aside from the one in question, are *exactly* the same.  Smalledatetime would not change this fact.  But as mentioned below, I might benchmark performance drain before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't do it that way, I would create another table that would store either the `A, B, or C` and the RecordID.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I can think of off the top of my head is that you will need to change your existing code and include all 3 fields if you want to get any use out of indexing on those bit columns.

Bit fields by their nature are not very selective.  To get good selectivity you will need to create a covering index on all 3 fields, and then include all 3 in your `WHERE` clauses so you get optimum seeks.

Answer (score 0):

Most databases will allocate a minimimum of the most efficient processing unit per field in any case so calling them bit fields would only be a metadata difference. But unpacking bits into words is just overhead anyway. You might as well use probably ints. And I'm pretty sure Sql Server doesn't index bit fields - cardinality of 2 doesn't help much.

50M records? A small number by most accounts.

Have you tried to quantify the overhead you're trying to reduce? If nothing else you're going to add work for the increased complexity.

I'd have to think a long time before increasing complexity.

Is this a really stable design otherwise, and you have some extra time?

Comment: If 50M is small... then how long can this table grow until it is "not small"?  There are only a couple of columns other than the PK's.